# How to check if an object has default values in C#

Tags: c#

I have an object that I want to check whether it contains default values or not, in the below code but that doesn't cut it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
           MyClass obj2 = null;

           if(obj1 == new MyClass())
            Console.WriteLine("Initialized");

           if(Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, new MyClass()))
              Console.WriteLine("Initialized");

        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Value {get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Value = 10;
    }
}
```

I have also used [Object.ReferenceEquals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx) but that doesn't cut it as well.

This is the **[fiddle](http://rextester.com/YTEX90091)** I am working on.

**Is there a way to check whether an object contains default values, or if the object is empty?**

---

**Edit: In case of an newly initialized object with many nested properties, how to check whether they contain a default value or not?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
           MyClass obj2 = null;

           if(obj1 == new MyClass())
            Console.WriteLine("Initialized");

           if(Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, new MyClass()))
              Console.WriteLine("Initialized");


        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Value {get; set; }

    public MyNestedClass MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Value = 10;
        this.MyProperty = new MyNestedClass();
    }
}

public class MyNestedClass
{
    public string SomeStringProperty { get; set; }

    public MyNestedClass()
    {
        this.SomeStringProperty = "Some string";
    }

}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://rextester.com/GQNB37922) in the case of nested objects.

Comment: You can loop through all of them, but it gets difficult to do if you have nested objects.

Comment: Yes it gets difficult to check in the case of deep nested objects.

Comment: What is your definition of _empty_ ?

Comment: @Steve If there is a list `List<int> someIntegerList = new List<int>();` this an empty integer list with count 0. Likewise, if I have my object of `MyClass` I didn't initialize a value to the `Value` property so the default value is 10, so in my opinion its an object with all default values.

Comment: That additional question you just added in your Edit is close to making your question too broad. You should consider asking a new question with a new example. I expect, however, that you'll be able to apply the same technique as the answer you've received; you'll just need to apply it recursively.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it becomes difficult real quick when it comes down to checking nested properties.

Comment: I didn't say it would be easy, but you've gotten an answer (a very good one) to your original question. Adding another question (especially one as potentially hazardous as that one) afterwards is considered bad form.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I updated my question to consider the case of nested objects.

Comment: ...which I recommended you not do. I said you should create a new question for that, since it's a new question. Oh well...

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? Does it really worth it? How much do you care for performance? Do you really need for arbitrary objects or only for a few specific ones? If an object is modified then values are restored to default one, is it important to be considered as being default. **WinForms** would use reflection and `DefaultValue` to determine if a property need to be saved for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your goal by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, creating and saving an immutable "default" instance, and comparing the value to it:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static readonly MyClass DefaultInstance = new MyClass();
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public MyClass() {
        this.Value = 10;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        var other = obj as MyClass;
        return other?.Value == this.Value;
    }
}
```

Now you can check if the instance is equal to a newly created one by calling

```
if (MyClass.DefaultInstance.Equals(instanceToCheck)) {
    ... // All defaults
}
```

You can change what it means for an instance to be "default" by altering `DefaultInstance` object.

**Note:** this trick works well only with immutable `MyClass`. Otherwise some code could perform `MyClass.DefaultInstance.Value = 20` and change the "default" object.

Comment: While this works for the very simple example the OP posted, how would you modify this to work with something that has nested (possibly built-in) classes?

Comment: @RonBeyer OP would have to define equality manually by providing a working implementation of `Equals`. There's simply no way around it.

Comment: You could also (if you didn't care about how long it took) serialize the data and compare it to a default value, which would avoid having to do recursion or looping through sub-objects, provided all the sub-objects are serializable.

Comment: @RonBeyer can you illustrate how to do that?

Comment: @RonBeyer you would not be able to avoid looping though - in case of serialization the loop would be hidden in the serialization code, but it would be there anyway.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Very true, although I'd avoid re-inventing the wheel if possible. An established library can handle that well, including reference loops.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this approach gets cumbersome real quick dealing with nested properties. I'd have to recursively override the respective `Equals` and `HashCode` methods of all my nested class definitions.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Absolutely, you do. You'd thank yourself for doing all this work later, when comparing objects for equality becomes easy and consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method using JSON serialization that allows you to check if the objects are equal or not:

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/22EiOt):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var defaultObj = new MasterObject();
        var notDefaultObject = new MasterObject();

        var defaultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(defaultObj);
        var notDefaultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notDefaultObject);

        Console.WriteLine("First Test");
        if (defaultJson == notDefaultJson) 
            Console.WriteLine("Same thing");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not same thing");

        notDefaultObject.Sub1.SomeObject.SomeOtherValue = "Not a default Value";

        notDefaultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notDefaultObject);

        Console.WriteLine("Second Test");
        if (defaultJson == notDefaultJson) 
            Console.WriteLine("Same thing");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not same thing");

    }

}


public class MasterObject 
{
    public SubObject1 Sub1 { get; set; }
    public SubObject2 Sub2 { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public MasterObject()
    {
        Sub1 = new SubObject1();
        Sub2 = new SubObject2();
        SomeString = "Some Default String";
    }
}

public class SubObject1 
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public SubObject2 SomeObject { get; set; }

    public SubObject1()
    {
        SomeObject = new SubObject2();
        SomeValue = "Some other Default String";
    }
}

public class SubObject2
{
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }

    public SubObject2()
    {
        SomeOtherValue = "Some default";
    }
}
```

Output:

> First Test
>
> Same thing
>
> Second Test
>
> Not same thing

What is happening is that you serialize the default object and then you make changes to the "not default object", re-serialize and compare again. **This can be slow** because you are generating strings, but as long as all the sub-objects can be serialized this will be the simplest way to compare if an object is "default" (what you get from `new`) or has been modified.

Comment: So do I decorate all my class definitions with `serializable` attribute to make them serializable to compare nested properties?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that unless you need to handle custom serialization, which shouldn't be the case for most objects.

Comment: Comparing so many strings would hurt performace in my opinion.

Comment: You could cache them, but it isn't comparing "so many strings", it is a single string. The slow part is the serialization, string comparison is relatively fast.